# Programmatically Added Textboxes not Appearing

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, controls

I'm using `WinForms` in `VS15` with `C#`.

I'm dynamically adding `TextBox`s and `Label`s to my `Form` based upon a user selected value in a `ComboBox` (essentially this looks up a value in a data collection which tells my UI what controls it needs).

When I attempt to generate the controls, the `Label`s appear and layout just fine, however, the `TextBox`s are remarkable in there absence.

I've tried fidelling with the `MaximumSize` and `MinimumSize` properties to see if they could be messing with something but it doesn't seem to be making any difference.

The code I use for doing this is below (I know the use of the `List<Pair<Label,TextBox>>` is pretty unecessary but I find it helps readability):

```
private void GenerateControls(string formType)
    {
        string[] formParameters = engine.GetFormParameters(formType);
        if (formParameters == null) return;
        SplitterPanel panel = splitContainer.Panel1;
        panel.Controls.Clear();
        List<Pair<Label, TextBox>> controlPairs = new List<Pair<Label, TextBox>>();
        int tabIndex = 0;
        Point labelPoint = panel.Location + new Size(20, 20);
        Size initialOffset = new Size(0, 30);
        Size horizontalOffset = new Size(40, 0);
        Size tBoxSize = new Size(40,20);
        foreach (string parameter in formParameters)
        {
            Label label = new Label
            {
                Text = parameter,
                Tag = "Parameter Label",
                Name = $"lbl{parameter}",
                Location = (labelPoint += initialOffset)
            };
            TextBox textBox = new TextBox
            {
                AcceptsTab = true,
                TabIndex = tabIndex++,
                Text = "",
                Tag = parameter,
                Name = $"txt{parameter}",
                MaximumSize = tBoxSize,
                MinimumSize = tBoxSize,
                Size = tBoxSize,
                Location = labelPoint + horizontalOffset
            };
            controlPairs.Add(new Pair<Label, TextBox>(label, textBox));
        }

        foreach (Pair<Label, TextBox> pair in controlPairs)
        {
            panel.Controls.Add(pair.First);
            panel.Controls.Add(pair.Second);
        }
    }
```

I don't believe that my use of `Point + Size` is the issue as the `Point` class overrides the `+` operator like so:

[image: Point+]

Comment: What's the point of controlPairs?  Just add the controls in the first loop.  Use the debugger to view your Location information.

Comment: I did say in my question that I think it helps with the readability of the code, I know it's a largely pointless construct and it will be removed once I have this running. As for locations, I'm getting the labels at (20;Y) and the textboxes at (60;Y) which looks fine to me unless I'm missing something.

Comment: The `Point` class overrides the `+` operator so that `Point + Size = Point`. The labels use the same method to work out their location, they seem to work fine. Any other ideas?

Comment: What happens if you remove the line `panel.Controls.Add(pair.First);`, do the TextBoxes show then?

Comment: @Equalsk yes... Why on earth is that happening?

Comment: @Steve new Size(40,20)

Comment: Oh jesus, The horizontal offset just wasn't big enough and they were behind the labels... That's embarrassing. Thanks guys

Comment: Beat me to it ;-) Glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately for me the issue appears to be simply that the dX was not a big enough value to prevent the text boxes from being hidden under the labels, I forgot that labels don't have transparent backgrounds.

While I was at it: I've removed the redundant `List<Pair<<>>`; added support for dynamically adjusting `TextBox` location based on `Label` size; and split it out into two separate loops, so my code now looks as below and works just fine:

```
    private void GenerateControls(string formType)
    {
        string[] formParameters = engine.GetFormParameters(formType);
        if (formParameters == null) return;
        SplitterPanel panel = splitContainer.Panel1;
        panel.Controls.Clear();
        int tabIndex = 0;
        Point labelPoint = panel.Location + new Size(20, 20);
        Size verticalOffset = new Size(0, 30);
        Size tBoxSize = new Size(200,20);
        int maxLabelLength = 0;
        foreach (string parameter in formParameters)
        {
            Label label = new Label
            {
                Text = parameter,
                Tag = "Parameter Label",
                Name = $"lbl{parameter}",
                Location = (labelPoint += verticalOffset),
                AutoSize = true
            };
            panel.Controls.Add(label);
            if (label.Size.Width > maxLabelLength)
            {
                maxLabelLength = label.Size.Width;
            }
        }
        Size horizontalOffset = new Size(maxLabelLength + 30, 0);
        labelPoint = panel.Location + new Size(20, 20) + horizontalOffset;
        foreach (string parameter in formParameters)
        { 
            TextBox textBox = new TextBox
            {
                AcceptsTab = true,
                TabIndex = tabIndex++,
                Text = "",
                Tag = parameter,
                Name = $"txt{parameter}",
                MaximumSize = tBoxSize,
                MinimumSize = tBoxSize,
                Size = tBoxSize,
                Location = labelPoint += verticalOffset
            };
            panel.Controls.Add(textBox);
        }

    }
```

Thanks everyone who helped!